# grub mode and no other os? even ubuntu 17.10 is not complete installed?

Tags: 17.10, windows-8, grub-efi

My Laptop: Sony Vaio E Series
Issue: Directly loading into GRUB mode.
grub> ls
output:
(hd0) (hd0,gpt1).....(hd0,gpt9)

but no msdos think like (hdo,msdos1)

Please help me to recover my laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you have live OS on usb try fallowing:

Boot PC with live OS

Connect to internet

Mount your partition where is `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Install `Grub-Customizer`

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Start `Grub-Customizer`

```
 sudo grub-customizer
```

You grub/partitions should be loaded. Click save. Close grub-customizer and reload.